# C# 2 List doesn't match

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
List<Object> rollerliste = (from row in roller.AsEnumerable() select (row["rolName"])).ToList();
List<Object> yetkiliste  = (from row in roller.AsEnumerable() select (row["Visible"])).ToList();
                    
for(int r = 0; r < rollerliste.Count(); r++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < yetkiliste.Count(); y++)
    {
         if(rollerliste[r].ToString() == "frmMasalar" && yetkiliste[y].ToString() == "true" && r == y)
         {
             cu.frmMasalar = 1;
         }
         else
         {
             cu.frmMasalar = 0;
         }
    }
}
```

Actually
`if(rollerliste[r].ToString() == "frmMasalar" && yetkiliste[y].ToString() == "true" && r == y)`
it seems to be checking for correct data but not working.

| rollerliste | yetkiliste |
| --- | --- |
| frmMasalar | True |
| frmYonetim | True |

I just want to make check rollerliste if column1 is true "button.Enable = true" or false

Comment: Try to explain to yourself what that loop is doing. But don't stop at the first loop, explain also the second one.

Comment: Calling `ToString` on these rows is a code smell, especially if `row` is of type `DataRow`. Use `.Field<T>()` to get the values as the appropriate type. If `row["Visible"]` is a `bool` instance, your comparison to `"true"` is wrong because `bool.ToString` returns `"True"`. Case matters when you're comparing the string, but if you get it as `bool` instead, you don't have to deal with that.

Comment: Furthermore, you're making things WAY too hard on yourself by separating the properties. The `r == y` condition is basically acting as a join condition to put them back together. Do *one* LINQ query and select an anonymous object with the two properties you need. The you don't need nested loops or `r == y`.

Comment: Finally, if you predicate your LINQ with `where row.Field<string>("rolName") == "frmMasalar" && row.Field<bool>("Visible")` (note: no ToString calls!), you can use `.Any() ? 1 : 0` on that and assign that to `cu.frmMasalar`. The whole method can be reduced to one statement.

Comment: For every item in those two loops, you update the same `cu.frmMasalar`. That does not seem right

Comment: What type is `roller`? If there is a database involved, what database do you use and what is the definition of the table schema?

Comment: Perhaps you want something like `cu.frmMasalar = roller.Any(row => row.Field<string>("rolName") == "frmMasalar") && row.Field<bool>("Visible")) ? 1 : 0;`, which combines madreflection's comment above with logic that tests for any "frmMasalar" row where "Visible" is true. If you expect at most one "frmMasalar" row, this might be clearer as `cu.frmMasalar = roller.Where(row => row.Field<string>("rolName") == "frmMasalar").FirstOrDefault(row => row.Field<bool>("Visible")) ? 1 : 0;`. The above could still be coded as an `if ... else ...`, if you prefer not to use the `?:` ternary operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Please note that, within your loops, you are overwriting `cu.frmMasalar` over and over again.** That alone might be the reason you're not getting what you want.

I'm not sure I totally understand what you want to do. But, check whether this might be simpler:

```
cu.frmMasalar = 0;
foreach(var row in roller.AsEnumerable()) {
  if((string) row["rolName"] == "frmMasalar" && (bool) row["Visible"]) {
    cu.frmMasalar = 1;
    break;
  }
}
```

There are also more condensed ways to do this, if the point is to find the one entry where `rolName == "frmMasalar"`:

```
cu.frmMasalar = 0;
var matchingRow = roller.AsEnumerable()
                        .FirstOrDefault(r => (string) r["rolName"] == "frmMasalar" 
                                             && (bool) row["Visible"]);
if(matchingRow != null)
   cu.frmMasalar = 1;
```